# Windows server 2012 essentials GPO AD/SYSVOL MISMATCH

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, windows-server-2012, essentials-2012, windows-server-essentials

I am having an issue with Group policys and will do my best to describe the issue below:

GPRESULT, ADSI and GPT.ini shows the group policy with mismatching AD/SYSVOL versions, the SYSVOL version always being 65536. However Gpresult also shows that the policy is applied.

Group policy managment shows the AD and SYSVOL versions as matching.

This happens to freshly created GPO's also. 
I've run out of ideas as I'm using an administrator account and the server was preconfigured.

Hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong and no mismatch, [the `GPT.ini` version number is just a bit tricky](http://blogs.technet.com/b/grouppolicy/archive/2007/12/14/understanding-the-gpo-version-number.aspx)

A value of `65536` is the same as `0x00010000`, and in hexadecimal form it's a bit easier to decipher.

The first 16 bits (`0x0001`) is the User settings version, indicating that this is the first revision.
The last 16 bits (`0x0000`) indicate that no computer settings have been included in the GPT yet.

Answer (score 1):

**"AD / SYSVOL version mismatch" message is displayed unexpectedly in the Group Policy Results report in Windows**
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2866345

**Symptoms**

Assume that you run the Group Policy Modeling Wizard from the Group Policy Management Console (GPMC) snap-in on a Windows 8-based, Windows Server 2012-based, Windows 8.1-based, or Windows Server 2012 R2-based computer. In this situation, the following message is displayed unexpectedly in the alerts section of the Group Policy Results report:
AD / SYSVOL version mismatch

**Notes**

- This issue also occurs when you use the Gpresult.exe command-line
  tool on a client computer.
- The alerts section of the Group Policy
  Results report displays the result of the comparison between the
  version of the Group Policy template and the version of the Group
  Policy Container (GPC) for each GPO.

**Cause**

This issue occurs because one or more Group Policy Objects (GPOs) cannot be applied because of security filtering or Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI) filtering.

More specifically, a Group Policy is filtered because the Group Policy reporting engine assumes that the GPOs that are related to the Group Policy use version 65535 of the Group Policy template. Therefore, when the assumed version value is compared with the current version value of the GPC that the GPO uses, a mismatch occurs. This mismatch is then reported in the Group Policy Results report.

Answer (score -1):

This happens when GPOs have incorrect Security Filtering or WMI Filtering, or when either of these two become corrupted on a GPO.  Please use [this link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2866345) to solve your issue.

Comment: Have any  luck with this?